# To modify a core eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In order to *modify* an eclipse plugin, what are the steps to find its editable code ?

I *read* and debug source provided with eclipse distribution but to try a fix in `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.codemanipulation` behavior I need to make it editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the source repository is available [at eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=eclipse.jdt), the plugin compiled with the source should be available from the standard eclipse update site.

I'm guessing you are considering changing the source, recompiling and using your plugin instead of the standard one? There is a different way to change functionality, its with fragments. For example, [look at a question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688519/patch-a-plugin-with-a-single-class), follow the links in my text and Andrews answer for more information.

Comment: Also use the git repos where available.